# Deploying an Application on Mac OS X doesn't work

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, build-process, qmake

I can build a project and have it run fine on my computer but when I run it on different computers it wont work. How can I build it with Qt so that all files libraries get included?

I am following this http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/deployment-mac.html
but it doesn't seem to work. When I run qmake it just prints out the instructions for them like

```
Mode:
  -project       Put qmake into project file generation mode
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as files to
                 be built,
                 defaults to *.c; *.ui; *.y; *.l; *.ts; *.xlf; *.qrc; *.h; *.hpp; *.hh; *.hxx; *.H; *.cpp; *.cc; *.cxx; *.C
                 Note: The created .pro file probably will 
                 need to be edited. For example add the QT variable to 
                 specify what modules are required.
  -makefile      Put qmake into makefile generation mode (default)
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as project files to
                 be processed, if skipped qmake will try to find a project
                 file in your current working directory
```

I run it inside the release directory for the app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

qmake on Mac OS X by default generates (deprecated) XCode project file. If you want to generate makefiles you need to run qmake with parameters:

```
qmake -spec macx-g++
```

Then you can call make. But if you want to deploy your app you need to run `macdeployqt` found in QTDIR/bin/ directory

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did figure out about macdeployqt soon after asking, I still don't understand how to follow that mac deployment guide on Nokia's website though. It doesn't mention anything about what you said nor about macdeployqt. So confusing...